# Why is my colpitts oscillator not working in LTSPice but work on breadboard?

Tags: oscillator

Here is a picture for circuit diagram.
I use **BC639** as transistor but I can't find this model in LTSpice. I use **BC547B** instead in LTSpice.

Vo is the  output for my circuit.

[image]

[image]

Here is what I see in real life from Oscilloscope.

[image]

My diagram came from Youtube tutorial.[Youtube link for Colpitts Oscillator NPN](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z761q6rk-tw)

[image]

Comment: 1. Your newly added diagram does NOT match your simulation diagram. The new diagram matches what Andy says. ie as he says you made an error in your simulation layout. || 2. Is C5 REALLY 100 uF. (No doubt the video would tell me if I spent 15m watching it.)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Thank you. I have already found my problem.

Comment: @kile --> [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @kile --> [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If my answer doesn't 100% cover what you need to know, leave a comment explaining what you want.

Comment: Kile, have you managed to fix this as per my advice regarding your circuit error?

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work in simulation because you have drawn it incorrectly: -

[image]

The capacitor I added is just an example. I advise you to check what particular Colpitts design you were following when you made this error.

Comment: Check my new edited question

Comment: No need to amend your question. It’s clearly obvious you have made a mistake in transferring the circuit to your simulator.